# Converting curl request to powershell using invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm struggling to try and convert the following curl request into powershell using invoke-webrequest:

```
curl -X PATCH "http://172.28.36.62:8080/api/3/http/upstreams/my-api/servers/5" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"down\": false}"
```

Gone and upgraded nginx and it uses a later version of the API with different commands and struggling to swap them over to powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your API is a REST API you can use the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://172.28.36.62:8080/api/3/http/upstreams/my-api/servers/5' `
    -Method Patch -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"down": false}'
```

Comment: That works a treat, thank you very much Christophe